# Getting an RTMP stream from Java

Tags: java, rtmp

I feel pretty stupid asking this, but I just couldn't find anything on the web that helped me.

Is there a way to connect to an RTMP stream from within a Java application?

I just need to connect and read a few bytes. I even don't need to play a video or anything.  It's only for monitoring the connection.

I tried using `java.net.URL` and even red5's `rtmpclient` and `rtmpconnection`, but couldn't figure out how it could help me.

Answer (score 1):

i found JUV RTMP Client that allows connecting to a RTMP Server.

it has the following highlights:

1.RTMP/RTMPT/RTMPS/RTMPE/RTMPTE protocols support (both AMF0 and AMF3 encodings)

2.Remote method invocation

3.Remote shared object management

4.Play and publish audio/video streams (supported by the server) (!audio/video codec implementations are not included!)